# Installing ganache-cli in a docker image (not standalone)

Tags: docker, truffle, ganache

I'm using alpine-openjdk image with s6-overlay for running services on docker. I'm trying to run ganache-cli on the same image, either as another service or as an initialization script, but couldn't get it to work. Is there an example of running ganache-cli with s6-overlay?

Thanks.

Here's what my DockerFile looks like:

```
FROM smebberson/alpine-openjdk

RUN apk update && apk add nodejs
RUN npm install -g ganache-cli

ADD etc /etc
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

---

Running ganache-cli & in cont-init.d

---

Getting the following error when running the image:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:52
*/var n=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols,a=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,i=Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable;e.exports=function(){try{if(!Object.assign)return!1;var e=new String("abc");if(e[5]="de","5"===Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[0])return!1;for(var t={},r=0;r<10;r++)t["_"+String.fromCharCode(r)]=r;if("0123456789"!==Object.getOwnPropertyNames(t).map(function(e){return t[e]}).join(""))return!1;var n={};return"abcdefghijklmnopqrst".split("").forEach(function(e){n[e]=e}),"abcdefghijklmnopqrst"===Object.keys(Object.assign({},n)).join("")}catch(e){return!1}}()?Object.assign:function(e,t){for(var r,o,c=function(e){if(null==e)throw new TypeError("Object.assign cannot be called with null or undefined");return Object(e)}(e),s=1;s<arguments.length;s++){for(var f in r=Object(arguments[s]))a.call(r,f)&&(c[f]=r[f]);if(n){o=n(r);for(var d=0;d<o.length;d++)i.call(r,o[d])&&(c[o[d]]=r[o[d]])}}return c}},function(e,t){e.exports=function(e,t,r){var n=t.
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js:12:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

Comment: If you post your Dockerfile and/or the error you're getting, it will be easier to help you solve the issue

Comment: added @NtokozoZwane.